# First Time User Setup

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I'm building a system with users and roles using Jetstream(Livewire)/Fortify auth, but it's a closed system (I mean, there is no way to register yourself, you must be invited) so I disabled Fortify's registration feature, but I want the first user to be able to register himself.

In other words: Fortify's registration should be off, but while there isn't an user in database, it should be on (email validation too, but If I can figure out the registration part, the verification should be easy).

I tried making an middleware to check if there isn't a registered user and redirect to register view, but I found some errors (like the view doesn't even exist 'cause fortify registration is off).

Does someone know a way to make this work using the Jetstream stack? Thanks!

Comment: I often write a command (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands) so I can just write in the terminal `php artisan make:user` and it will create an admin user and password. The command basically just does `User::create()` with some predefined attributes. Perhaps this would help in your situation too

Comment: @Djave yeah, I'm trying to stick to my plan, but if I can't solve this problem, I should do something like that. Thnx for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

and what about this, in the FortifyServiceProvider.php boot method

```
Fortify::registerView(function () {
    if(!User::all()->count())
        return view('auth.register');
    else
      abort(404,'No registration allowed');
});
```

Comment: I can try that way, but I was thinking about something more integrated and automatic. that way the user would still need to choose to access the registration route, I would still need to delete the registration link in welcome view and it's a bit hacky, but I can't think in a better way since the middleware way didn't work. thanks for your help! what I thought was to make this registration path mandatory while there was no user, after that the functionality would be completely disabled.